# Push notifications and REST

Tags: android, http, rest

I'm just beginning to learn about REST and push notifications and am looking to see if I'm correct in what I'm thinking.

1.) -
A push notification is sent when the server changes state and has the advantage over constantly pinging the database for the most updated data, when it has new data it just sends it out to whomever is listening.

2.) - 
You have to use REST to have a push notification.  This I'm not really too sure about, is it possible to send push notifications without using REST?

Comment: rest and (whatever technology you use for) push are totally unrelated concepts.

Comment: Well, that clears up one thing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different services to send push notifications. IBM Bluemix www.ibm.com/bluemix, Facebook www.parse.com and a few others that make it easier to send push notifications without using REST. Good luck